# Minha página em manutenção, sem ser visível para admin

Tags: wordpress, redirecionamento

Eu comecei agora a trabalhar num site em wordpress, mas o meu cliente gostaria de pôr uma página em manutenção totalmente personalizada. Estive a ver alguns alguns plugins mas nenhum deles me dá liberdade total para isso, para desenvolver o `HTML/CSS` em 100%. Sei que posso fazer um redirect mas o problema é que eu tenho de ir desenvolvendo o site ao mesmo tempo. O que eu estou à procura é de uma solução para que as outras pessoas vejam a página de manutenção (totalmente feita por mim, HTML/CSS, na 'root' http://example.com/) mas eu, caso esteja login como admin do site, poder ir desenvolvendo e ver o site real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, Miguel,

Acho que o que você quer fazer, exatamente dessa maneira, não é possível no WP (posso estar enganado).

O que você pode fazer, que daria um resultado semelhante, é:

1) Criar uma página comum lá em "Páginas >> adicionar nova", Tirar o cabeçalho dela e tudo mais (aquelas opções no final do editor da página), e inserir tudo em texto nela, escrevendo todo o seu HTML lá, e fazer referência ao CSS em "Custom CSS" (que a localização depende do tema). Agora você vai em "Configurções >> Escrita/leitura" (não lembro em qual, mas é a 3ª opção) e vai seleciona essa nova página como Home (página estática). Pronto, quando alguém acessar http://www.seudominio/ vai cair nessa página aí, que você não deixou link, cebaçalho, menu nem nada. Aí pra você acessar o painel ADM basta acrescentar o /wp-admin normalmente.

2) Se a (1) não responde a tua pergunta, talvez eu tenha entendido errado e você queira personalizar totalmente a página 404. Vai em "Aparência >> Editor" e procura, num menu lateral a direita da página (uma lista de arquivos) pela página 404. Aí no espaço do meio, editor de texto, vai aparecer o conteúdo da página 404. Vai ter um codigo php com  "get_html" ou "get_text" ... algo do tipo. Tira isso e manda ver lá no HTML. Faz referência ao CSS la no custom CSS.

Nos dois casos, o CSS pode ser feito diretamente no arquivo de estilo (estilo.css ou layout.css, depende da língua) em "Aparencia >> editor".

Num terceiro modo de fazer isso...

3) Você ainda pode fazer assim. Digamos que a ou o cliente tenha o domínio exemplo.com, você upa o WP lá e tal, e cria um diretório dentro do www (public_html) na raíz do domínio, chamado "construcao" ou qualquer coisa que lembre isso. Aí instala o WP nesse diretório aí. Então o WP só acessado em "exemplo.com/construcao/". Na raíz mesmo, fora do diretório, você cria um index.html e um index.css só pra essa página de manutenção.

Espero ter ajudado

Abraço

Comment: Muito Obrigado, acho que vou pela opção 1

Answer (score 0):

Vá ao diretório de plugins do Wordpress e procure por Maintenance Page, é o primeiro plugin que vai aparecer nos resultados, criado por themegrill.

Segue a lista de recursos do plugin:

Responsive design looks great on your devices.
Logo Upload
Background image/color option
Subscriber Feature to collect emails
Download subscriber list as csv
Social icons
Font Color option
Add title, text message option
Option to exclude page
Custom CSS
Maintenance Page Pro:
Counter
Contact Form
MailChimp integration
Ip Whitelist
Background Slider
Background Video
Progress Bar
Google font option
Analytic Code Option
Role Based access
Font size option
About Page

É a solução mais rápida que encontrei pra você.
Do contrário, você terá de criar uma página de php com o HTML/CSS e jogar os Hooks do wordpress dentro dela, e que eu me lembre, isso é uma alteração no template.